# Python 3.6 EOF error and using xargs to parallelize scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, eof, xargs

I'm attempting to parallelize many python script executions on bash by using xargs. However, I need to use the standard output of a bash "for loop" as standard input for my python scripts.

My bash script:

```
#Collect number of CPUs
cpus=$( ls -d /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[[:digit:]]* | wc -w )

#Collect data.input directories and pass to xargs to execute python scripts.

arr=$(find . ! -path . -mindepth 2 -type d)

DIR_present=$(pwd)
for dir in $arr; do
        cd $dir
        printf '%s\0' "$(pwd)/data.input"
        cd $DIR_present
done | xargs -0 -x -n 1 --max-procs=$cpus python Foo.py
```

Foo.py works perfectly when executed manually. However, executing this bash script results in an "EOF" error for each "data.input":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Foo.py", line 254, in <module>
    data_file = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Thanks!

- Changing `input()` into `raw_input()` does not work.
- The correct `data.input` paths are being collected. I have "echoed" the paths and manually executed Foo.py with them.

Comment: It would help a lot if you provided a [mre]. To start, all the file stuff seems irrelevant, so remove it. Use static data instead, in the Bash script itself.

Comment: Also you might want to run the script through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: I actually figured it out, using "sys.argv[1]" in place of "input()" solved the issue.